# Pyspark DataFrame - How to convert one column from categorical values to int?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe and I want to convert one of that column from string to int. Example:

**Tabela 1**:

```
+------------+-----+
|categories  |value|
+------------+-----+
|         red| 0.23|
|       green| 0.34|
|      yellow| 0.56|
|       black| 0.11|
|         red| 0.67|
|         red| 0.34|
|       green| 0.45|
+------------+-----+
```

**Table 2**:

```
+------------+-----+
|categ_num   |value|
+------------+-----+
|           1| 0.23|
|           2| 0.34|
|           3| 0.56|
|           4| 0.11|
|           1| 0.67|
|           1| 0.34|
|           2| 0.45|
+------------+-----+
```

So, in that case: [red=1, green=2, yellow=3 and black=4].

But I don't know all the colors in order to assign it manually. *So, I need one way to do the attribution automatically.*

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code work for me:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c")],
["id", "category"])

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer

Answer (score 1):

In the case you want a solution with less code and your categories do not need to be ordered in a special way, you can use `dense_rank` from the pyspark functions.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("categ_num", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("categories")))
```

Keep in mind, that window functions can cause longer runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) as part of SparkML.